# can we do a play and pause kind of thing in web automation with or without selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

What if I need to pause the automation script and play it dynamically. 
just like a music player.

Comment: What do you mean by "play it dynamically"?  What would be an example of playing it dynamically vs. playing it not dynamically?

Comment: i mean to say i need to stop the automation script in between at any point of time and then resume from there onwards

Comment: It would be easier to understand and answer your question if you could update your question to contain some context. Like why you want to stop it and what for actions you would like to preform. Explaining the flow of your application and test maybe. We could even come with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Running tests from an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) should give you the possibility to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging). You can set a [breakpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) in the IDE. When you run the test in debug mode and hit the point of the breakpoint the test will stop executing the next commands of the code. When the debugger stops executing the code at the breakpoint you should be able to play freely with the browser. In the IDE you can continue the code again when you are done investigating.

So in your analogy the breakpoint is the pause button and the continue button of the IDE is the play button. You can set as many breakpoints as you like. Some IDE's even support pausing the playback of the code at any point in time.

Each programming language and IDE should support the debugging process. How to set it up for your tools is another question. I suggest you ask help from your development team.

Keep in mind Selenium-server has a [session time-out of 30 minutes](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3224), so you must continue playback within 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Niels. I was expecting this from you. :) 

can you please look into this also, http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23093/how-we-can-enter-data-into-multiple-fields-at-the-same-time-to-make-automation-f

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify an operating system.  On Linux, you can suspend any running process like this:

```
kill -SIGTSTP PID
```

where PID is the ID of the process.  To resume the process, do this:

```
kill -SIGCONT PID
```

You can do a similar thing on Mac OS:

```
kill -STOP PID
kill -CONT PID
```

I don't know about Windows.

Comment: I think you cannot interact with the process if you stop it, or can you? Still its intressting

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal No, you can't interact with it when it's stopped.

Answer (score -1):

In .net use driver.sleep(-what ever the time you want to pause the test-);

After time ends, test will automatically start.

Comment: that is what we are asking where to stop but what i want is to stop at any point of time and any number of times.

Comment: Yeah. any point, any number of time.Its better to stop after completing your test steps,like at the test cleanup stage.

Comment: no bro, in your way we are giving it before running where, when, and how much to stop. 
but i need it at run time.

Comment: Please explain it bit more.At this point i cant understand what you are trying to implement.

Comment: ok let me try again. 
take a music player analogy, we can play and pause a song at any point of time
in the same way I need to play and pause the program under execution 
is it fine ?

Comment: Ahh,,im not sure.. let me try it for myself.And sory for misunderstanding the questions.But Dig deep in to MS test manger. when you are executing a codedui script at MS test manager it allow you to pause the test.

Comment: A sleep function would work to investigate, but not to continue afterwards when you are doing manipulating the browser. Unless you wait for X period. Better is to learn to use and configure a debugger. I would only use sleep for just very simple situations and fast tests..